# How to find the width and height of an irregular shaped object in an image by scanning?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a segmented image, which has irregular shaped objects in it. I want to calculate the area,width and height of the irregular shaped objects. I scanned the image and wrote
[image]

```
i=imread('cameraman.tif');
[m n ]=size(i)
for i=1:m
for j=1:n
```

How to check whether the pixel is black or white? According to my logic while scanning the no.of pixels in the row is the width and the number of pixels in the column is the height and total number of pixels is area. Is the logic correct?

I want the width of white objects.

[image]

This is the labeled image attached with the data set. How can I compare the segmented image with this labeled image? Is it easy to use a sliding window to find the width and height of segmented image as compared to that of the labeled image? I need a code without using the `regionprop` function.

Comment: Can you share a sample image?

Comment: Now, do you want to count number of white pixels or please explain clearly what do you want to do. Specially what you have tried so far.

Comment: i want to calculate the width and height and area of white objects. Is it the no.of pixels ?how to check it?

Comment: Your requirement is still unclear to me. If you need only the width of each white blob, then my answer below provides it. If you need the width of the big rectangle bounding all the white blobs, still you can find it simply by finding the min and max of all the small bounding boxes. If you need to count the white pixels only, just loop through each bounding box. Pls use an example to show us what do you mean by 'I need a logic without using regionprop.'

Comment: i need a pixel-by-pixel matching. since regionprop includes black pixels also,i can't use it. after finding the width and height i need to compare it with the labeled image and calculate accuracy

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question as long as you haven't clearly defined the width and height of an object.

Comment: sir i need the width and height of segmented image

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Yes, I too agree with you and stepping down from this question. I still cannot understand what he wants :-(.

Comment: how the white pixel is counted and width is calculated

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to find the area of the bounding rectangle of each white blob. If you need to count the number of white pixels, now you can easily elaborate from here. Let us know after you try.

```
img = imread('TcpZy.png');
imshow(img);

s = regionprops(img);

for i = 1:length(s)
    bb = s(i).BoundingBox;
    rectangle('Position', [bb(1),bb(2),bb(3),bb(4)],...
        'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1)
    fprintf('\ni = %d\tarea = %f', i,s(i).Area);
end
```

Output:

```
i = 1   area = 42.000000
i = 2   area = 52.000000
i = 3   area = 76.000000
i = 4   area = 92.000000
i = 5   area = 40.000000
i = 6   area = 99.000000
i = 7   area = 182.000000
i = 8   area = 103.000000
```

Output image:

[image]

**Update 1:**

I update the answer to make it complete.

```
clc; clear all;

img = imread('TcpZy.png');
imshow(img);

s = regionprops(img);
figure;

for i = 1:length(s)
    bb = s(i).BoundingBox;

    r1 = round(bb(2));
    c1 = round(bb(1));
    w = bb(3);
    h = bb(4);
    r2 = r1+h-1;
    c2 = c1+w-1;

    img2 = img(r1:r2,c1:c2);
    subplot(2,4,i);
    imshow(img2);

    nw = sum(img2(:));

    fprintf(['\ni = %d\tbbarea = %.1f\tsrow = %d\tscol = %d\theight = %d'...
        '\twidth = %d\twhite=%d'], i,s(i).Area,r1,c1,h,w,nw);
end

fprintf('\n');
```

Output:

```
i = 1   bbarea = 42.0   srow = 15   scol = 143  height = 7  width = 15  white = 42
i = 2   bbarea = 52.0   srow = 42   scol = 147  height = 5  width = 15  white = 52
i = 3   bbarea = 76.0   srow = 69   scol = 150  height = 6  width = 19  white = 76
i = 4   bbarea = 92.0   srow = 99   scol = 153  height = 7  width = 21  white = 92
i = 5   bbarea = 40.0   srow = 222  scol = 154  height = 10 width = 14  white = 40
i = 6   bbarea = 99.0   srow = 129  scol = 155  height = 8  width = 24  white = 99
i = 7   bbarea = 182.0  srow = 193  scol = 155  height = 11 width = 26  white = 182
i = 8   bbarea = 103.0  srow = 161  scol = 158  height = 8  width = 21  white = 103
```

So `bbarea` or the `Area` parameter of the `BoundingBox` gives the number of white pixels (or the ON pixels). To show it to you I calculated the number of white pixels in each area separately, and it is the same. Hence if you want the area including both white and black pixels (or ON and OFF pixels), you can multiply width and height of each `BoundingBox`.

Output image: This figure now shows extracts of each `BoundingBox`.

[image]

If you want to see the width and height of the area encloses all the white blobs, try the following.

```
clc; clear all;

img = imread('TcpZy.png');
imshow(img);

s = regionprops(img);
bb = vertcat(s(:).BoundingBox);

r1 = min(bb(:,2));
c1 = min(bb(:,1));
h = max(bb(:,2)+bb(:,4))-r1+1;
w = max(bb(:,1)+bb(:,3))-c1+1;
rectangle('Position', [c1,r1,w,h],...
        'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1);

fprintf('\nw = %d\th = %d',w,h);
```

Output:

```
w = 39  h = 218
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: i think this area includes the holes present in the object

Comment: @abcd: why did you state "I need a code without using the regionprop function" and accepted an answer that contradicts it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i need an accurate width. otherwise i cant compare it with labeled image.regionprop will include black pixels too

Comment: black pixel means pixel which is of not interest